# Signup page upon submission leads to error Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have built a site, where the user upon successful signup should be redirected to the login page. However it is not occurring so. Attached below are the relevant files:

Signup page html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <h1>Sign Up</h1>
  <form method="POST" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% buttons %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html"),name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name="signup"),
]
```

views.py:

```
class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
    template_name = "accounts/signup.html"
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: change the success_url = reverse_lazy("login") to success_url = reverse_lazy("accounts:login")

Comment: Can you specify which type of form is use and give th forms.py code please,

Comment: Got it sorted bmons. I thought that if the htmls' were in the same folder I do not need to mention "accounts".

Comment: lalit, I am using a usercreationform. bmons solution worked for me!